Google sheets - Trying to make my counting script work
I have a counting script that I've used before that counts changes in cells in several columns on my tab called "Pipe" to my destination tab called "Brain".
I just copied it to this new sheet that I created and I can't get it to work for some reason, I didn't make any changes to it except updating the URL to the new destination sheet but nothing happens.
It has worked perfectly before so any ideas that it doesn't?
Here is the a link to the new sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZrqKeROY1yxsj3-wrCajmcU8fItbCD8pVJizxyHTfl8/edit?usp=sharing
Here is the code:

function allInOne01(e) {

  // some variables  
  const sheetToWatch = 'Pipe';
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();

  // test if edit is is a value, AND in correct Sheet AND in correct row
  if (!e.value || sheet.getName() !== sheetToWatch || e.range.rowStart <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1))
  {
    // if failed end processing
    return;
  }

  // an array of Column Sets
  const colSets = [[7,1,15],[8,2,16],[9,3,17],[10,5,19],[11,6,20]]; // columnCtart, countColumn#1,countColumn#2
  // create an array of columnStart values
  var columns = colSets.map(function(e){return e[0];});
  // find the columnStart in columns
  var result = columns.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: result = "+result)
  if (result !== -1){ // if -1, then value not found, otherwise value = zero-based index
    const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZrqKeROY1yxsj3-wrCajmcU8fItbCD8pVJizxyHTfl8/edit#gid=27102914") //id of spreadsheet
    const targetSheetName = 'Brain'; //fill in name of other sheet/tab
    const targetSheet = targetSs.getSheetByName(targetSheetName)
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: CountColumn#1: "+colSets[result][1])
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: CountColumn#2: "+colSets[result][2])
    const countColumn1 = colSets[result][1]; 
    const countColumn2 = colSets[result][2]; 
    // increment count1
    const countCell1 = targetSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn1); 
    countCell1.setValue((Number(countCell1.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
    // increment count2
    const countCell2 = targetSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, countColumn2); 
    countCell2.setValue((Number(countCell2.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
    // Logger.log('DEBUG: Complete');
  }
}

I tried other scripts that I knew worked before when counting cell changes but it doesn't work.
I tried to make changes in the script and also look it through to see if there is something wrong with the code but I can't find anything

Hi! Did you setup the trigger on the new project?

I only changed it slightly but your version would have probably worked as well
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh1 = e.range.getSheet();
  const fr = sh1.getFrozenRows();
  if (e.value && sh1.getName() == 'Pipe' && e.range.rowStart > (fr)? fr:1) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1");
    const colSets = [[7, 1, 15], [8, 2, 16], [9, 3, 17], [10, 5, 19], [11, 6, 20]];
    var columns = colSets.map(function (e) { return e[0]; });
    var idx = columns.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
    if (~idx) {
      //e.source.toast("Gate2"); 
      const tss = e.source;
      const tsh = tss.getSheetByName('Brain')
      const rg1 = tsh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, colSets[idx][1]);
      rg1.setValue((Number(rg1.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
      const rg2 = tsh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, colSets[idx][2]);
      rg2.setValue((Number(rg2.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
    }
  }
}


Hi Cooper! Your change works, it just a slight delay and yeah I don't know why my version didn't work since it had worked before. I created a new clean sheet. Thanks for the help!
